# .htaccess files directive only matching when I'm checking the same folder

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, files

I've got a server set up where I want a specific PHP file to be readable via the browser, but I want access to be denied to the rest of the PHP files. So I put this `.htaccess` in the server root:

```
<Files "*.php">
    Require all denied
</Files>
```

Then, I put this in a subfolder (let's say the folder is `subdir`) to match specific files:

```
<Files "folder/specific.php">
   Require all granted
</Files>
```

But it doesn't work. It only works if I put this directly in `subdir/folder/specific.php`:

```
<Files "*.php">
   Require all granted
</Files>
```

Why does it happen like that? Even if I use:

```
Order Allow, Deny
Allow from all
```

The same thing happens.

Comment: You’ve tagged the question `apache-2.2`, however, if you are using `Require all denied` etc. then you must be on `apache-2.4` I assume? (Unless you are perhaps on a LiteSpeed server which is incorrectly reporting the server as Apache 2.2?)

Comment: @MrWhite yup, you're right. I mistagged it. It's corrected now. I just went for the first Apache tag that appeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<Files>` directive is not expected to have any path components, only the base file name component.  There should be no slashes in the directive's argument, and `*` doesn't match slashes (as it normally works in the system shell, by the way). The [`core` module documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#files) states:

> The directives given within this section will be applied to any object with a basename (last component of filename) matching the specified filename.

Obviously, the basename of a filesystem object (the thing after the last `/`) can not match anything that contains a slash.

As it is suggested in the page describing [configuration sections](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#file-and-web), to match specific files in specific directories, you normally nest `<Files>` within the corresponding `<Directory>`:

```
<Directory "/var/web/dir1">
    <Files "private.html">
        Require all denied
    </Files>
</Directory>
```

This implies it is **wrong** to write this as a single `<Files "/var/web/dir1/private.html>`. In your case, I suspect the server should have been complaining somewhere in the error log that `.htaccess` has incorrect directive.

Since `.htaccess` can not contain `<Directory>` section and itself corresponds to the directory path it is placed into, this translates to adding your `<Files>` section into the `.htaccess` file placed in the same directory where the target files are located (or any of its parents), and not using any path within the directive. This is exactly what you are did when "it only works".

Note also, the [`.htaccess` documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/htaccess.html) **begins with**:

> You should avoid using `.htaccess` files completely if you have access to httpd main server config file. Using `.htaccess` files slows down your Apache http server. Any directive that you can include in a `.htaccess` file is better set in a [Directory](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) block, as it will have the same effect with better performance.

So, the *only* benefit they provide is ability to alter some configuration of the server without accessing its configuration. Everything else is possible; if you have that access (and you certainly have, else the question here would be off topic), you should convert your `.haccess` into in-server configuration and disable `AllowOverride`, removing any performance penalty it incurs. The details of how to do that provided on the same page, under *Merging of `.htaccess` with the main configuration files* sub-header.

Answer (score 0):

Following on from [@Nikita Kipriyanov's answer](https://serverfault.com/a/1152654/49157) with some alternatives, as creating an additional `.htaccess` file in the subdirectory is not always desirable, possible or even necessary.

As stated, the `<Files>` directive matches filenames only, not file-paths. It is applied to the directory that contains the `.htaccess` file and all subdirectories there of.

If the file you wish to grant access to is "unique" in the directory tree that the `.htaccess` file applies to then you don't necessarily need to create an additional `.htaccess` file in that subdirectory (which is often undesirable) since allowing access to that filename in the parent/root `.htaccess` file is usually "good enough". For example:

```
<Files "*.php">
    Require all denied
</Files>

<Files "specific.php">
   Require all granted
</Files>
```

These two `<Files>` blocks can be combined into a single `<FilesMatch>` directive using a regex and a negative lookahead. For example:

```
<FilesMatch ^(?!specific\.php).+\.php$>
    Require all denied
</FilesMatch>
```

However, you can be more specific and include the full file-path by using an `<If>` expression. For example:

```
<Files "*.php">
    <If "%{REQUEST_URI} != '/subdir/folder/specific.php'">
        Require all denied
    </If>
</Files>
```

The outer `<Files>` container isn't necessarily required as you could do everything in the `<If>` expression. For example:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ /\.php$/ && %{REQUEST_URI} != '/subdir/folder/specific.php'">
    Require all denied
</If>
```

Or, using a negative lookahead (as used earlier) in a single expression:

```
<If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^(?!/subdir/folder/specific\.php).+\.php$#">
    Require all denied
</If>
```

Or, you can use mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/subdir/folder/specific.php
RewriteRule \.php$ - [F]
```

Reference:

- `<Files>` - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#files
- `<FilesMatch>` - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#filesmatch
- `<If>` - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#if

  - Apache Expressions - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html
- `RewriteRule` (mod_rewrite) - https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule